# Any way to use auto-completion in Eclipse column mode

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin

I love both of the two features as they tremendously improves my coding speed. However,it seems that when I'm in column mode(block selection mode), auto-completion only works for one line and will break out of the column mode. Is there any way to combine them two？

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know in Eclipse Neon. However, that's a good feature to request via http://bugs.eclipse.org

Comment: Thanks for confirming！